# How do I remove or reset all xrdp settings for user

Tags: xorg, remote-desktop, xrdp

I am running xrdp on my Ubuntu 18.04 computer.
I got 3 users. Two is working well. They can connect from Windows 10 rdp without any problem. But the last one does fail with a "Connection problem, giving up" message. And it is that user I use myself.

I have spend a lot of time researching and looking at log-files without any luck. I did remove and install xrdp again - no change.

I might have done something to corrupt the settings for this user. It did work for some time. If I only could somehow reset the user.

The user is not logged on locally. I use gnome desktop. From inxi for one of the functioning users i got this info:

Desktop: Gnome 3.28.2 Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Display Server: X.Org 1.19.6

**EDIT**

I compared an OK user with the malfunctioning user by looking at /var/log/xrdp.log. For the OK user, the log continues after:

```
 [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: started connecting
```

while the other just gets a bunch of:

```
 [DEBUG] Closed socket 17 (AF_UNIX)
```

and after a while these lines appears:

```
 xrdp_wm_log_msg: connection problem, giving up
 xrdp_wm_log_msg: some problem
```

There are some differences in .xorgxrdp.10.log

Bad one:

```
  [ 22202.422] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/libglx.so
  [ 22202.425] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
  [ 22202.425]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
  [ 22202.425]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
  [ 22202.425] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  390.48  Wed Mar 21 23:42:56 PDT 2018
    ...
  [ 22202.428] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
```

Good one

```
[ 24242.838] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[ 24242.839] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 24242.839]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[ 24242.839]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
...
[ 24242.843] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[ 24242.843] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[ 24242.869] (II) IGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[ 24242.870] (II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[ 24242.870] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
```

**Edit** xrdp.ini added

```
cat /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
[Globals]
; xrdp.ini file version number
ini_version=1

; fork a new process for each incoming connection
fork=true
; tcp port to listen
port=3389
; 'port' above should be connected to with vsock instead of tcp
use_vsock=false
; regulate if the listening socket use socket option tcp_nodelay
; no buffering will be performed in the TCP stack
tcp_nodelay=true
; regulate if the listening socket use socket option keepalive
; if the network connection disappear without close messages the connection will be closed
tcp_keepalive=true
#tcp_send_buffer_bytes=32768
#tcp_recv_buffer_bytes=32768

; security layer can be 'tls', 'rdp' or 'negotiate'
; for client compatible layer
security_layer=negotiate
; minimum security level allowed for client
; can be 'none', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'fips'
crypt_level=high
; X.509 certificate and private key
; openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
certificate=
key_file=
; set SSL protocols
; can be comma separated list of 'SSLv3', 'TLSv1', 'TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1.2'
ssl_protocols=TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2
; set TLS cipher suites
#tls_ciphers=HIGH

; Section name to use for automatic login if the client sends username
; and password. If empty, the domain name sent by the client is used.
; If empty and no domain name is given, the first suitable section in
; this file will be used.
autorun=

allow_channels=true
allow_multimon=true
bitmap_cache=true
bitmap_compression=true
bulk_compression=true
#hidelogwindow=true
max_bpp=32
new_cursors=true
; fastpath - can be 'input', 'output', 'both', 'none'
use_fastpath=both
; when true, userid/password *must* be passed on cmd line
#require_credentials=true
; You can set the PAM error text in a gateway setup (MAX 256 chars)
#pamerrortxt=change your password according to policy at http://url

;
; colors used by windows in RGB format
;
blue=009cb5
grey=dedede
#black=000000
#dark_grey=808080
#blue=08246b
#dark_blue=08246b
#white=ffffff
#red=ff0000
#green=00ff00
#background=626c72

;
; configure login screen
;

; Login Screen Window Title
#ls_title=My Login Title

; top level window background color in RGB format
ls_top_window_bg_color=009cb5

; width and height of login screen
ls_width=350
ls_height=430

; login screen background color in RGB format
ls_bg_color=dedede

; optional background image filename (bmp format).
#ls_background_image=

; logo
; full path to bmp-file or file in shared folder
ls_logo_filename=
ls_logo_x_pos=55
ls_logo_y_pos=50

; for positioning labels such as username, password etc
ls_label_x_pos=30
ls_label_width=60

; for positioning text and combo boxes next to above labels
ls_input_x_pos=110
ls_input_width=210

; y pos for first label and combo box
ls_input_y_pos=220

; OK button
ls_btn_ok_x_pos=142
ls_btn_ok_y_pos=370
ls_btn_ok_width=85
ls_btn_ok_height=30

; Cancel button
ls_btn_cancel_x_pos=237
ls_btn_cancel_y_pos=370
ls_btn_cancel_width=85
ls_btn_cancel_height=30

[Logging]
LogFile=xrdp.log
LogLevel=DEBUG
EnableSyslog=true
SyslogLevel=DEBUG
; LogLevel and SysLogLevel could by any of: core, error, warning, info or debug

[Channels]
; Channel names not listed here will be blocked by XRDP.
; You can block any channel by setting its value to false.
; IMPORTANT! All channels are not supported in all use
; cases even if you set all values to true.
; You can override these settings on each session type
; These settings are only used if allow_channels=true
rdpdr=true
rdpsnd=true
drdynvc=true
cliprdr=true
rail=true
xrdpvr=true
tcutils=true

; for debugging xrdp, in section xrdp1, change port=-1 to this:
#port=/tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_display_10

; for debugging xrdp, add following line to section xrdp1
#chansrvport=/tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_chansrv_socket_7210


;
; Session types
;

; Some session types such as Xorg, X11rdp and Xvnc start a display server.
; Startup command-line parameters for the display server are configured
; in sesman.ini. See and configure also sesman.ini.
[Xorg]
name=Xorg
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
code=20

[X11rdp]
name=X11rdp
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
xserverbpp=24
code=10

[X11rdp2]
name=Custom
lib=libvnc.so
username=askallan
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=ask5901

[Xvnc]
name=Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
#xserverbpp=24
#delay_ms=2000

[console]
name=console
lib=libvnc.so
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5900
username=na
password=ask
#delay_ms=2000

[vnc-any]
name=vnc-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=ask
port=ask5900
username=na
password=ask
#pamusername=asksame
#pampassword=asksame
#pamsessionmng=127.0.0.1
#delay_ms=2000

[sesman-any]
name=sesman-any
lib=libvnc.so
ip=ask
port=-1
username=ask
password=ask
#delay_ms=2000

[neutrinordp-any]
name=neutrinordp-any
lib=libxrdpneutrinordp.so
ip=ask
port=ask3389
username=ask
password=ask

; You can override the common channel settings for each session type
#channel.rdpdr=true
#channel.rdpsnd=true
#channel.drdynvc=true
#channel.cliprdr=true
#channel.rail=true
#channel.xrdpvr=true
```

Comment: Did you check `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`?

Comment: My assumption is, that files shared by all users will not cause this issue. But I might be wrong. I will add xrdp.ini.

Comment: Hmm my memory is failing me. I was certain there was a user section in there.

Comment: Does the differences in .xorgxrdp.10.log indicate anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your "good" user is picking up xorg driver instead of the nvidia driver, so you need to check the user-specific files such as `~/.xsession` and anything related to xorg or graphics drivers.